# Web frameworks to develop for Android and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android, frameworks

Web frameworks to develop for Android and iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pretty much any client-side web framework. Some will have more mobile-friendly features than others. Just to name a few:

- [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200192/how-to-use-gwt-on-mobile-devices) for some discussion of GWT on mobile)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

As for server-side application frameworks (i.e. [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) or [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)), you can certainly use anything you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

Any server platform/framework will do, both Android and iPhone have pretty standard browsers. Just don't use Flash, Silverlight or similar plugins. Stick to the w3c standards and you should be fine.